# Why did Americans oppose Richard Nixon's visit to China? What "past policies" were Nixon going against?

Tags: united-states

Many people opposed Nixon's visit to China. Why? I read an article saying people complained that Nixon's visit to China was going against past policies. What policies were they referring to?

Article Link: https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/nixons-great-decision-on-china-40-years-later/2012/02/10/gIQAtFh34Q_story.html?utm_term=.ec447d11de8c

Comment: What article? Can you provide a link?

Comment: Uncited source  no evidence of research. Vtc

Comment: A brief look at the article gave me this: "A typical Nixon blast was his 1964 comment during a trip to Asia that “it would be disastrous to the cause of freedom” for the U.S. to recognize Red China, which is precisely what he ended up doing. " Vtc for lack of research.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the article, it is difficult to be certain, but it was probably a reference to the [comment that Nixon had made](https://www.academia.edu/11060075/Nixon_and_China) during his trip to Asia in 1964. He said that:

> “it would be disastrous to the cause of freedom”

if the United States recognised Red China.

Obviously, by [visiting China in 1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1972_Nixon_visit_to_China), that was precisely what he did.

Comment: And it went against the US doctrine of [**containment**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Containment) by George Keenan.

Comment: Kennan's Containment stategy was rather specific in targeting the Soviets.  Peeling one communist power from another wasn't much contemplated by Kennan.  Rather, though ultimately sound, it gave us Viet Nam.